# Pass a parameter containing '%' in URL?

Tags: javascript, jsp, url

While passing my url, for example `something:8000/something.jsp?param1=update&param2=1000&param3=SearchString%&param4=3` , I am getting following error:

```
Bad Request

Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
```

I know `SearchString%` which I need to pass as a parameter, has the issue. Then how to pass a 
parameter containing '%' in URL??

Comment: Why are you passing % ? you should append it server side.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980/best-practice-escape-or-encodeuri-encodeuricomponent

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use %25 in place of %
In URLs % has a special meaning as an escape character

Special characters like (space) can be encoded like %20 (the ascii code for space/32 in hex)

Therefore a percent sign itself must be encoded using the hex code for % which happens to be 25

You can use http://www.asciitable.com/ to look up the appropriate hex code under the hx column

Alternatively, if you are doing this programatically (ie. with javascript) you can use the builtin function `escape()` like `escape('%')`

Comment: (It's a nice thing [this conversion method already exists](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent). See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980/best-practice-escape-or-encodeuri-encodeuricomponent), and avoid use of `escape` here.)

Comment: Also see ["Comparing escape(), encodeURI(), and encodeURIComponent()"](http://xkr.us/articles/javascript/encode-compare/) which discusses *why to avoid `escape`*.

Answer (score 6):

See this: [Encode URL in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/how-to-encode-a-url-in-javascript)

Basically you need to make sure the variables you are passing are encoded (the '%' character is a special character in URL encoding).

Any special characters - %,?,&, etc... need to be encoded. They are encoded with '%' and their hex number.  So '%' should become '%25', '&' becomes '%26', etc.

**Update**: see [When are you supposed to use escape instead of encodeURI / encodeURIComponent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980/best-practice-escape-or-encodeuri-encodeuricomponent) for why you should avoid using escape.

Comment: definitely use encodeURIComponent.  Most notably it converts "+" which escape leaves alone.